# Datatables Bootstrap theme not applying when using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, requirejs, themes

I am fairly new to RequireJS, so please be gentle!

Below is a link with my HTML and JS and if you run it you will see that the ***datatable is initialized correctly*** but it is not applying the bootstrap theme.

**Link with problem:**

https://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/c2f7s2jz/2/

What am I doing wrong?

Below is my JS (in case the fiddle doesnt work):

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'jquery': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery',
    'bootstrap': 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min',
    'datatables': 'https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.12/b-1.2.2/b-colvis-1.2.2/b-html5-1.2.2/cr-1.3.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.1.3/r-2.1.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.0/datatables.min',

  },
  shim: {
    'bootstrap': {
      deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'datatables': ['jquery', 'bootstrap'],

  }
});


require([
  'jquery',
  'bootstrap', , 'datatables'
], function($, Bootstrap, datatables) {
  'use strict';

  $('#example').dataTable();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.12/b-1.2.2/b-colvis-1.2.2/b-html5-1.2.2/cr-1.3.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.1.3/r-2.1.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.0/datatables.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed dt-responsive data-table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

 <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
...
</tbody></table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a number of problems with what you are trying to do:

1. The [file](https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.12/b-1.2.2/b-colvis-1.2.2/b-html5-1.2.2/cr-1.3.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.1.3/r-2.1.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.0/datatables.min.js) you use for `datatables` in `paths` looks like it contains a bunch of anonymous AMD modules concatenated together. An anonymous module is a module for which the `define` call does not set the module name. Such modules get their module name from the `require` call that initiated their loading. **You cannot just concatenate anonymous modules to make a bundle.** The calls to `define` must *also* be changed to add the module name as the first argument to the `define` call. That file may be useful for people who do not use any module loader, but you cannot use it with RequireJS.

   So you have to setup separate `paths` for `datatables` and `datatables.bootstrap`.
2. Your `shim` for `datatables` is useless because `datatables` calls `define` and `shim` is only for files that do **not** call `define`.
3. If you want to use the Bootstrap stylings for Datatables, then you must load `datatables.bootstrap` one way or another. You currently do not do that. (Even if the bundle you load was fixed to work with RequireJS, you'd have to explicitly request `datatables.bootstrap` somewhere.)
4. `datatables.bootstrap` will try to load `datatables.net` rather than `datatables`. You need to refer to `datatables` as `datatables.net` everywhere or you can use a `map` like I do below.

I get proper results if I modify your JavaScript to this:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'jquery': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery',
    'bootstrap': 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min',
    'datatables': 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min',
    'datatables.bootstrap': 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min',
  },
  shim: {
    'bootstrap': {
      deps: ['jquery']
    },
  },
  map: {
    '*': {
      'datatables.net': 'datatables',
    }
  },
});


require(['jquery', 'datatables.bootstrap'], function($) {
  'use strict';

  $('#example').dataTable();
});
```

Here's a forked [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3u2h5ebv/).

Comment: absolutely brilliant answer sir. I was using that same bundle (built by the datatables builder) for non-requireJS apps and somehow stupidly thought it would work even in an AMD world.I understood your explanations perfectly. Since I needed more plugins for the datatables, i have downloaded them separately and "moduled" them individually.

I wish I could upvote your answer multiple times!

Comment: So if you do use a path to (incorrectly) specify a concatenated bundle, will those anonymous modules overwrite each other? So the concatenated bundles that the DataTables author supplies are essentially useless, right? They define anonymous modules that can't be used.