# requirejs and datatables loading extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, requirejs

I try run datatables and requirejs. without extras it work but together not.

Why this not work ?

```
requirejs.config({
    appDir: ".",
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
        'jquery': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min',
        'bootstrap': '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min',
        'datatables.net': 'https://cdn.datatables.net/s/bs-3.3.5/jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.10,af-2.1.0,b-1.1.0,b-colvis-1.1.0,b-flash-1.1.0,b-html5-1.1.0,b-print-1.1.0,cr-1.3.0,fc-3.2.0,fh-3.1.0,kt-2.1.0,r-2.0.0,rr-1.1.0,sc-1.4.0,se-1.1.0/datatables.min', //normally this should be stored locally
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'datatables.net': {
            deps: ['jquery','bootstrap']
        }
    }
});

require(['jquery','datatables.net'], function($) {
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

Here is example
http://jsfiddle.net/42ucpwee/1/

Comment: You're facing the same problem as the question against which I closed yours: the file you use for `datatables.net` is not correctly structured to be loaded by RequireJS. See the explanation in [the answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45308784/1906307). Tangential issue: you should remove the `shim` for `jquery`, as it is useless.